# Исправить код для бота на Pyrhon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

При запуске бот должен записывать id и введённый пароль в БД, но вместо пароля он записывает первое введённое сообщение (команда '/start'). Помогите исправить данный недостаток.

```
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, types
bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def password_vvod(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль:')
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)", (message.chat.id, message.text))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция password_vvod из вашего примера срабатывает по команде /start. Соответственно, в эту функцию передается сообщение `/start`, после чего вы сразу же записываете это сообщение в базу данных.

Для решения вашей проблемы потребуется использовать конечную машину состояний. Полноценный пример использования можете посмотреть [вот здесь](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py)

Для начала понадобится указать хранилище для этих состояний. Достаточно импортировать MemoryStorage и указать его в Dispatcher

Далее создаем класс с нашими состояниями.

Класс должен наследоваться от StatesGroup. password_input и будет нашим состоянием

```py
class UserState(StatesGroup):
    password_input = State()
```

При вводе команды /start установим пользователю состояние password_input: `await UserState.password_input.set()`. После этого бот будет реагировать только на обработчики сообщений с состоянием password_input, то есть, даже если сейчас вы введете /start, то бот проигнорирует вас

Собственно, нужно сделать этот самый обработчик для написанных пользователем с таким состоянием сообщений. Достаточно указать в message_handler нужное состояние `@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.password_input)`

В аргументах функции не забываем указывать `state: FSMContext`, это позволит управлять состоянием пользователя, на пример, передавать какие-либо данные между разными состояниями и обработчиками (как в примере с гитхаба, который я скинул выше). В данном случае он нужен нам для того, чтобы завершить текущее состояние у пользователя после ввода пароля и вернуть в первоначальный вид `await state.finish()`

Полный код будет выглядеть так

```py
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

bot = Bot(token='')

storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class UserState(StatesGroup):
    password_input = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль:')
    await UserState.password_input.set()
    

@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.password_input)
async def password_input(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)", (message.chat.id, message.text))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```